# Object Detection API v2 Tflite model post quantization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, quantization

I try to convert and quantize a model trained with the Object Detection API v2 to run it on a Coral Devboard.

It seems like there is still a big problem with exporting Object Detection Models to lite, though I hope that maybe someone has some advice for me.

my converter looks like the following and I try to convert "SSD MobileNet v2 320x320" from [Model Zoo v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)

```
def convertModel(input_dir, output_dir, pipeline_config="", checkpoint:int=-1, quantization=False ):

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'

files = os.listdir(input_dir)
if pipeline_config == "":
    pipeline_config = [pipe for pipe in files if pipe.endswith(".config")][0]
pipeline_config_path = os.path.join(input_dir, pipeline_config)


# Find latest or given checkpoint
checkpoint_file = ""
checkpointDir = os.path.join(input_dir, 'checkpoint')
for chck in sorted(os.listdir(checkpointDir)):
    if chck.endswith(".index"):
        checkpoint_file = chck[:-6]
        # Stop search when the requested was found
        if chck.endswith(str(checkpoint)):
            break
print("#####################################")
print(checkpoint_file)
print("#####################################")
#ckeckpint_file = [chck for chck in files if chck.endswith(f"{checkpoint}.meta")][0]
trained_checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpointDir, checkpoint_file)


configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path)
detection_model = model_builder.build(configs['model'], is_training=False)

ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
    model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(trained_checkpoint_prefix).expect_partial()


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.seq = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.Input([300,300,3], 1),
        ])

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.seq(x)
        images, shapes = self.model.preprocess(x)
        prediction_dict = self.model.predict(images, shapes)
        detections = self.model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
        return detections

km = MyModel(detection_model)

y = km.predict(np.random.random((1,300,300,3)).astype(np.float32))
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(km)
if quantization:
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [ tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS, tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.representative_dataset = _genDataset
else:
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(os.path.join(output_dir, 'model.tflite'), 'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

My Datagenerator loads about 100 images downloaded from the coco dataset to generate sample inputs

```
def _genDataset():
sampleDir = os.path.join("Dataset", "Coco")
for i in os.listdir(sampleDir):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(sampleDir, i))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (300,300))
    image = image.astype("float")
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=1)
    image = image.reshape(1, 300, 300, 3)
    yield [image.astype("float32")]
```

I tried to tun the code with TF2.2.0 which returned me

```
RuntimeError: Max and min for dynamic tensors should be recorded during calibration
```

according to an update to TF2.3.0 should help when then returns me

```
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': Ops that can be supported by the flex runtime (enabled via setting the -emit-select-tf-ops flag):
tf.Size {device = ""}
```

I also tested tf-nightly (2.4.0) which returns again

```
RuntimeError: Max and min for dynamic tensors should be recorded during calibration
```

Right now this tf.Size operator seems to be the reason why I can convert the model because when I allow custom operations I can convert it to tflite.
Sadly that is not a solution for me because the coral converter or my interpreter can't use the model with a missing custom op.

Does someone know if there is a possibility to remove this op in postprocessing or just ignore it during conversion?

> Just converting it to TFlite without quantization and tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS works without problems

Comment: any progress? facing the same issue